# How to monitor IP allocation within an AWS subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm working inside a corporate AWS account. My subnets associated with a VPC are running out of available IP addresses. I could not find any clear way to see how the existing IP addresses are allocated within a subnet. 
Is there an easy way to see this information from the UI console?

Comment: Do you want to know how many IPs have been allocated, or what they've been allocated to?

Comment: @Parsifal, I'd like to see what they've been allocated to.

Comment: To view where they have been allocated, look at the **Network Interfaces** tab. However, it's not always easy to figure out which resource is using each ENI, so sometimes it is easier to look at the lists of resources (eg EC2 instances).

Answer (score 1):

To determine the specific IP addresses being within AWS the best source is to list all available Network Adapters and look at their attached private IPv4 addresses, however some resources like ELBs will not have an API action to list the private IPv4 address they use.

You can get a count of remaining IP addresses in each subnet by performing the following from within the console:

- Access VPC interface
- Click Subnets
- Select your subnet
- View the value of property `Available IPv4 Addresses

You can also view this on the subnets page under the column header of `Available IPv4`.

If you want to access the property programmatically use the [describe-subnets](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-subnets.html) function to view subnets. Then check for each subnet the value of the `AvailableIpAddressCount` property.

Comment: Yes, this is clear. What I'm trying to see is the allocation of assigned (not available) IP addresses. I.e. which EC2 instances or other AWS resources are using the IP addresses in a particular subnet.

Comment: In which case there is no easy way to see this, it could be split between any number of resources some of which don't have an API action to retrieve private IPs such as ELBs.